# ffserver ffmpeg stream mjpeg from webcam Logitech C930e to mjpeg format without re transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, logitech-webcam, mjpeg, ffserver

I have premium webcam from Logitech (C930e) and this camera support mjpeg built in processing directly in the camera it self. My purpose is to get that stream with ffmpeg and pipe it to ffserver so its can be streamed to web browser in mjpeg format. The problem is although my webcam already producing mjpeg but the ffmpeg or ffserver is still do a transcoding. So its useless process eating all my CPU.

This is my ffserver configuration

```
        HTTPPort 8090
        HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
        MaxClients 20
        MaxBandwidth 500000
        NoDaemon

        <Feed webcam.ffm>
        file /tmp/webcam.ffm
        FileMaxSize 10M
        </Feed>

        <Stream webcam.mjpeg>
        NoDefaults
        Feed webcam.ffm
        Format mpjpeg
        VideoSize 640x360
        VideoFrameRate 30
        VideoBitRate 10280
        VideoQMin 1
        VideoQMax 1
        NoAudio
        </Stream>

        <Stream index.html>
            Format status
        </Stream>
```

This is my ffmpeg output:

```
    sudo ~/bin/ffmpeg -v verbose -r 30 -s 640x360 -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm
    ffmpeg version N-78619-g778439b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
      configuration: --prefix=/home/pi/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/pi/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/pi/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
      libavutil      55. 18.100 / 55. 18.100
      libavcodec     57. 24.105 / 57. 24.105
      libavformat    57. 26.100 / 57. 26.100
      libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
      libavfilter     6. 34.100 /  6. 34.100
      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x231a290] fd:3 capabilities:84200001
    [mjpeg @ 0x231ae10] Changing bps to 8
    [mjpeg @ 0x231ae10] EOI missing, emulating
    Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
      Duration: N/A, start: 5997.091177, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, 1 reference frame, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360, -5 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    [tcp @ 0x231f7a0] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
    [tcp @ 0x2325f20] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x231def0] w:640 h:360 pixfmt:yuvj422p tb:1/30 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
    [scaler for output stream 0:0 @ 0x231e1f0] w:640 h:360 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
    [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x231def0] TB:0.033333 FRAME_RATE:30.000000 SAMPLE_RATE:nan
    [scaler for output stream 0:0 @ 0x231e1f0] w:640 h:360 fmt:yuvj422p sar:0/1 -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuvj422p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
    Output #0, ffm, to 'http://localhost:8090/webcam.ffm':
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2016-02-23 01:32:00
        encoder         : Lavf57.26.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, 1 reference frame, yuvj422p(pc), 640x360, q=1-1, 10280 kb/s, 30 fps, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.24.105 mjpeg
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/10280000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [mjpeg @ 0x231b750] overread 3
    [mjpeg @ 0x231b750] EOI missing, emulating
    frame= 4000 fps= 15 q=24.8 size=  228156kB time=00:02:13.33 bitrate=14017.9kbits/s speed=0.501x
```

as you can see

Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))

instead it should be

Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)

I can not figure out, what causing ffmpeg to ignore the -c:v copy flag... 
is it because ffserver forced it to transcode no matter it is already in the same format? Or i have something wrong with my command?

Please help... :) I need to stream my mjpeg webcam to the web without re-transcoding, because i purchase that camera is to help my Raspberry Pi 2 (removing the need to do the transcoding in the Pi)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but it seems like what you were looking for.

From https://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html#Stream-specifiers-1:

> An empty stream specifier matches all streams. For example, `-codec copy` or `-codec: copy` would copy all the streams without reencoding.